PHP Session Causing Page To Not Load
This is a bug seen on the production server. On dev instance the code seems to be working just fine. Infact, in multiple different AWS instances the code is running just fine.
The Bug:
On loading a specific page that's pageA.php, the session is getting problematic. Before trying to load pageA.php all other pages are loading perfectly fine. But as soon as I load the page pageA.php, all other PHP pages stop loading. ( keeping loading for 5 min+ ) & at show HTTP 503 error.
currently pageA.php is loading a lot of values into session for quick referencing data. & is infact working just find on all other AWS instances.
I've tried restarting the IIS server. Again same story, all pages load fine, until I load pageA.php. Then everything stops loading with the 503 error.
Checked server machine for load, CPU at 2-5% & Memory at 10% utilization. So doesn't seem to be any kind of heavy load on the system either.
Tried destroying & recreating session in another PHPfile.
<?php

session_start();
session_destroy();
session_start();

// Check if there are any session variables set
if (!empty($_SESSION)) {
    echo '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">';
    echo '<tr><th>Session Index</th><th>Value</th></tr>';
    
    // Loop through each session variable and print its index and value
    foreach ($_SESSION as $index => $value) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($index) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars(print_r($value, true)) . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
} else {
    echo 'No session variables are set.';
}

?>

But even this file refused to load & goes to HTTP 503.
I've removed the session_start() & all other related code, just tried
echo " Hello ";

Works just fine. So my diagnosis is something is wrong with session, but can't figure out how to debug it or what the issues exactly is. Can't share code due to confidentiality. Any help in debugging is appreciated.

Are sessions enabled?

@Alessandro Login working fine at session are correctly enabled. Only the page navigation to pageA.php is the issue.

What is the code of pageA.php? Does this problem affect only the current session, or does it affect any session? In other words, if one user hits pageA.php does the website also stop working for other users?

It could be something as simple as pageA.php setting a session value over which some other code, used by all the pages, times out.

@KIKOSoftware The code loads hundreds of table rows into sessions. As soon as pageA.php is hit, none of other pages work for other users as well. Even login page stops working. ( all pages including sessions ) As for session overwriting, shouldn't the above code resolve it with session_destroy() ?

You could try to use session_destroy(); without first using session_start();, because nothing in the manual says you cannot. But if that will work? I don't know. Anyway, one of my golden rules says: "Only use things for their intended purpose.". Sessions provide a way to preserve data across subsequent accesses. Their intended purpose is to remember who the user is. You, however, use the session to loads hundreds of table row for quick referencing. That sounds like the wrong usage. Isn't there another way to do this, like caching?

I know you want to, some way or another, make your current solution work. But there's very little information in your question. All we know is that it is a IIS server with big session files. Did you check the PHP error logs? Any errors reported there?

As I iterated before, the same code is working in several different instances perfectly fine. I acknowledge your concern for proper use of session, but as this pre-written legacy code, there's not much  I can do until we've exhausted every other possible solutions. The problem is not being able to debug this issue, nor am I able to reproduce this issue to my local / dev instance. So any other approaches to at least find our the exact issue would be greatly helpful. Any way I can physically on disk check what sessions values are stored?

Yes, session files are stored on the disk. Use phpinfo() and check session.save_path. Did you intentionally not answer my question about checking the PHP error logs?

@KIKOSoftware No, I couldn't find the path for the error log on prod machine. Will need to search it as its not visible in phpinfo() either. Any idea where it could be on IIS server? if there's anything needs to check in IIS CPanel?

You could try and located the logs of your web server. There's also another way to find the session save path. Note that you need to use this before session_start(). Perhaps you could add the session section of phpinfo() to your question? Other people reading your question will see it without having to read all the comments, and there might be more information in it that can be relevant. Sorry, I don't use an IIS server nor CPanel, so I'm not the right person to answer your question.
